# Parent class to expose standard methods, child class to provide sub-methods to do the work

Tags: python-3.x, class, inheritance

I'd like to set up a parent class that defines a standard interface and performs common things for all children instances. However, each child will have different specifics for how these methods get the job done. For example, the parent class would provide standard methods as follows:

```
class Camera():

    camera_type = None

    def __init__(self, save_to=None):
        self.file_loc = save_to

    def connect(self):
        self.cam_connect()
        with open(self.file_loc, 'w'):
            # do something common to all cameras


    def start_record(self):
        self.cam_start_record()
        # do something common to all cameras
```

Each of these methods refers to another method located only in the child. The child classes will have the actual details on how to perform the task required, which may include the combination of several methods. For example:

```
class AmazingCamera(Camera):

    camera_type = 'Amazing Camera'

    def __init__(self, host_ip='10.10.10.10', **kwargs):
        super(AmazingCamera, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.host_ip = host_ip

    def cam_connect(self):
        print('I are connectifying to {}'.format(self.host_ip))
        # do a bunch of custom things including calling other 
        # local methods to get the job done.

    def cam_start_record(self):
        print('Recording from {}'.format(self.host_ip)
        # do a bunch more things specific to this camera

### etc...
```

With the outcome of the above providing an interface such as:

```
mycamera = AmazingCamera(host_ip='1.2.3.4', save_to='/tmp/asdf')
mycamera.connect()
mycamera.start_record()
```

I understand fully that I can simply override the parent methods, but in cases where the parent methods do other things like handling files and such I'd prefer to not have to do that. What I have above seems to work just fine so far but before I continue creating this I'd like to know if there is there a better, more pythonic way to achieve what I'm after.

TIA!

Comment: In ```AmazingCamera.start_record()```, you could first make a call to ```super().start_record()``` and then continue with your ```AmazingCamera``` code.

Comment: What you have is fine.

Comment: Thanks guys. Both methods work well. I decided to go the super() route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opted to keep the standard methods identical between the parent and child and minimize the use of child-specific helper methods. Just seemed cleaner.

As an example:

```
class Camera():

    camera_type = None

    def connect(self):
        with open(self.file_loc, 'w'):
            # do something common to all cameras
```

Then in the child I'm overriding the methods, but calling the method of the parent in the override as follows:

```
class AmazingCamera(Camera):

    camera_type = 'Amazing Camera'

    def cam_connect(self):
        print('I are connectifying to {}'.format(self.host_ip))

        # call the parent's method
        super().connect()

        # do a bunch of custom things specific to
        # AmazingCamera
```